# How to produce and consume multi-module NPM packages written in Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, module, package

I have, for quite some time now, been very comfortable creating and consuming NPM packages using Typescript, but with those packages essentially being provided and consumed as a single module.  I would now like to publish packages that have more than one module in them without requiring the consumer to import more of that package than they want in their code.

Assume I have two typescript modules in my package src folder, one in the file one.ts, and the other in the file two.ts:

one.ts:

```
export function talk() { console.log("Hello World"); };
```

two.ts:

```
export function talk() { console.log("Goodbye World"); };
```

Now, using best practices for creating an NPM package in Typescript, I also create in my src folder the index.ts file:

index.ts:

```
import * as one from "./one";
import * as two from "./two";
export { one, two };
```

And how there will be in my package's dist folder the files index.js, index.d.ts, one.js, one.d.ts, two.js, and two.d.ts (and probably also source mapping files not relevant to this question).

Here is the (somewhat abbreviated) package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "dist/",
  "types": "dist/",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --skipLibCheck",
    "prepublish": "yarn run build",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {},
  "files": [
    "src",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

And similarly the somewhat abbreviated tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Now I publish that package and consume it in typescript (after, of course, the npm -i) with the following:

```
import * as conversation from "my-package"
conversation.one.talk();  // Hello World
conversation.two.talk();  // Goodbye World
```

But now assume that I want to ONLY import the module one.ts.  I only ever say "hello", and not "goodbye".  **IMPORTANT:  I don't even want "goodbye" packed into my consuming code.**  (In my case, I'm using webpack to bundle the consuming code).

So I want to somehow be able to ask the import to ONLY import one.ts.  I don't really care what the syntax looks like, as long as I can do this:

```
import * as greeting from "my-package.one";  // I know this doesn't work
greeting.talk();
```

I also would really really LIKE to be able to do this:

```
import { talk } from "my-package.one";  // Again, I know this doesn't work
talk();
```

I know how to do this if writing javascript and creating my own header files with ambient modules.  But I don't want to do anything fancy like that.  I just want to use modules AS MODULES that are clearly there in the package as installed in node-modules.

Any pointers that might suggest a modification to how I am building the multi-mode package and/or how I am consuming it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
import { talk } from "my-package/dist/one"
```

Comment: Holy cow, thank you.  This is the one thing I didn't try.  I thought everything would be relative to dist already.  Thanks.

Comment: And to make the code easier to read, I have altered my packaging slightly so that distribution is to the "modules" folder.  So now I can say:

import { talk } from "my-package/modules/one";